# Deployment failed on heroku - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Im having a problem to deploy a new version of my Ruby on Rails app on heroku.

Heroku build log:

```
    -----> Ruby app detected
    -----> Installing bundler 2.0.2
    -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
    -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.6
           Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
           Old: ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-linux]
           New: 
    -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
           Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
           /usr/bin/env: ‘bash’: Argument list too long
           Bundler Output: /usr/bin/env: ‘bash’: Argument list too long
     !
     !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
     !
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
     !     Push failed
```

**Important notes:**

1. I haven't changed the Ruby version;
2. I've tryed to deploy another Ruby on Rails app, and realize that i'm not able to deploy any Ruby on Rails app.

Anyone with the same problem or any idea to help?

Comment: Are you deploying from a Windows machine?

Comment: Your problem is from bundler `argument list too long`, have you looked it up? I've seen a couple of threads with the same problem, it might be coming from the path used by `bundle`

Comment: @andreofthecape From a macbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is related to a buildpack version released at July, 13. I solved the issue removing this update and specifying the version of Ruby buildpack

`$ heroku buildpacks:remove heroku/ruby`

and then

`$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby#v217`